# C++ Keylog Not Working Properly

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple keylogger in C++ (for learning only) and it's not quite working how I would like it to. My goal is to have it write to a txt. Here's the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#define LOG(x) logger << x;

int main()
{
    using std::ofstream;
    using std::fstream;

    ofstream logger("logger.txt", fstream::app);

    char ascii;
    bool typing;

    for(;;)
    {
        if(_kbhit())
        {
            typing = true;
            ascii = getch();
            while(typing == true) //tried 'if', doesn't work
            {
                LOG(ascii);
                std::cout << ascii << std::endl;
                //typing = false;
                //break
                //tried using the above two and didn't work
            }
        }
        else typing = false;
    }

    logger.close();
}
```

When I make `while(typing == true)` continuous, the key that is pressed continuously gets printed, but at least it actually gets saved to the txt. When I try to make the loop stop after one keyboard click, nothing gets saved to the txt.

So what am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: i used your commented code and only switched `getch` for `_getch` because of my compiler and it works, not sure what is your problem.

Comment: hmm... still not working for me. I can not get it to save one character but then the program exits straight after.

Comment: On Windows I get the same problem as @ArchieGertsman.  Also, I don't like your `#define LOG(x)`.  Please either use a function or just write what you mean to make your code clearer.  The preprocessor should only be used when necessary.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman yes, the program exits after, but for me it appends the character you typed to the end of the file, is that not what it does for you?

Comment: @Pedro Sassen Veiga yes, it does the same for me. But I would like for it to keep going.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `typing` is never set to false, so it stays true and your loop continues.  The following code works:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream logger("logger.txt", std::fstream::app);

    for(char ascii; ascii != 3;)
    {
        ascii = getche();
        logger << ascii;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`getche()` prints the character typed, and `3` is the ASCII code for `Ctrl+C`.  This logs all characters, even non-printable ones.

A few comments on your code:

- Don't use macros (`#define`) unless you are substituting a large amount of code and using it often, or plan on changing what something does.
- You use loops and variables where you don't need to.  `getch` and related functions wait for input.
- `logger.close()` is automatically done when `logger` goes out of scope and is destructed.
- `return 0` should be at the end of `main`.  It's not necessary, but it is used to return to the OS and `return 0`, although automatically put in, is important to have in for clarity.
- I personally don't use `using` statements.  Just write out the namespace, it helps avoid collisions.  That's why it's in a namespace.

Comment: This isn't working for me either, as my computer is giving an abort message.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman Even with normal compiler options, this works for me.  It's valid code.  Maybe `getche` is messed up for your computer.  Try substituting `getch`.